# Annoying auto scroll of partially displayed items in WPF ListView

Tags: wpf, listview, scroll

I have a **ListView** in **WPF**, my problem is if an item is partially displayed and I click on item, the list will automatically scroll so the whole item will be visible.

How can I disable this **Auto Scroll** feature?

Thank you

Answer (score 22):

had the same problem and i've found a sulotion :)

in the Xaml you define a style for the ListViewItem with this EventSetter:

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
         <EventSetter Event="RequestBringIntoView" Handler="ProjectListView_OnRequestBringIntoView"/>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```

in code behind:

```
private void ProjectListView_OnRequestBringIntoView(object sender, RequestBringIntoViewEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Hope this will work for you too :)

Comment: In my case, i wanted the item to scroll into view, but i wanted it to be selected.  In my handler i just set the new selection and leave the e.handled=false.  works great!

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for :-)

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of ListView is call `BringIntoView()` after it was clicked. You can add an event handler to `PreviewMouseDown` event and handle it by set `e.Handled = true;`.

Comment: Do you have event handler subscribe to this event or you need to use it to do something else?

Comment: I just need ListView to work as usual, just I need to remove this BringIntoView behaviour

Comment: This behavior always occurs after the click event raised. You have to choose. Another way that might be possible is create a custom control and override `OnPreviewMouseDown`.

Comment: Overall : This is the only way, capture PreviewMouseDown and do what you like :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a work around, my ListView is displaying Photo items in MVVM

```
private void lv_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var p=e.OriginalSource as FrameworkElement;
        if (p != null && p.DataContext is **Photo**)
        {
            lv.SelectedItem = p.DataContext;
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Ekk's answer, you have to handle the bringIntoView event NOT on the parent listView but in the children event.
In my peculiar case for example my listBox has some runtime-code create elements. Those can be basically stackpanel of textboxes or, at the end a stackpanel of buttons.

[image]

Despite the fact of how those are made I just have have added

```
btnOk.RequestBringIntoView += (s,e) => { e.Handled = true; };
```

to each of those and the effect was that, after clicking, they were not brought into view but the action associated with each of them was immediately executed.

Answer (score -3):

Setting `ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"` for the list view helped.