# WinRT: prevent ListView from scrolling when partially visible item is tapped

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I have an app that shows entries in a ListView. Some entries are long, some are short. When user clicks (or taps) on a entry, app shows entry page. Pretty standard.
But there's one thing that bothers me a lot. When entry is long (and can't be fully displayed, just because phone screen is not big enough) and user taps at it, ListView automatically scrolls into the end of the entry. This is really annoying and I want it to stop.

I found exactly the same issue, but for [WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928356/annoying-auto-scroll-of-partially-displayed-items-in-wpf-listview). `RequestBringIntoView` is not available in Windows Runtime.

Comment: Are you looking for [ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.bringintoviewonfocuschange.aspx) perhaps? Downside would be if you ever set the IsSelected or something elsewhere it would stop bringing into view for you.

Comment: @ChrisW., no, that's not it.

Comment: Not an elegant solution but you can disable `ListView`'s `ScrollViewer` on `ItemClick` event for a while.

Answer (score 0):

When someone clicks on an item in the listView disable the listView to lock it but as Hassan has said it is not the best solution but it can save you time.