# WPF: Click partially visible row in listbox will scroll up instead of activating controls in the item

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, listbox

I have checkbox as item in a list box.

If you click a partially visible row in the listbox it will scroll up the list view to make the item fully visible, but not check the checkbox.

[image: Before Click]
[image: After Click]

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what your question is. Please add more information and post some of your code.

Comment: you can bind the IsSelected property of listboxitem to the IsChecked property of Combobox in your data template

Comment: we ran into this today too.  the better explanation:  the first click in the listbox on the partially visible row *scrolls the listbox* instead of letting the click to the item underneath.  (or more probably, scrolls the listbox, so now the click event started one row and ended on another, so it is possibly ignored)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be solved by handling the RequestBringIntoView Event.
I had a similar problem with a button in the ListViewItem. When the ListViewItem was only partially displayed at the bottom of the list, the ListViewItem just scrolled into view, rather than executing the Command associated with the Button.
See this answer: [Annoying auto scroll of partially displayed items in WPF ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928356/annoying-auto-scroll-of-partially-displayed-items-in-wpf-listview)
This worked for me.